# de-select selected value in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to de-select input value that was selected by `.select()` ?

The input is readonly

Have tried to use `.blur()` but the input value is still selected

```
const input = $('#'+input_id).select();
navigator.clipboard.writeText(input.val());
input.blur();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `blur` you can use this:

```
input[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0);
```